# Visual Studio 2012 does not generate exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, exe

I've a C++ project in Visual Studio 2012 Express, and I started having problems lately. When I compile the project it works, nothing wrong, however when I try to execute it the .exe disappears. I mean, I compile the project, the project generates the exe file with no problems, but if I try to execute it from Visual Studio or directly from the output directory, Windows say to me:

```
Cannot start the program 'C:\Users\Adrian\Dropbox\MyApp\Debug\MyApp.exe'.
The system can not find the file specified
```

If I create another project, Hello World for example, there is no problem and the exe generates and executes good. So I guess the problem is specific to my project. I tried disabling Avast (because maybe he delete the file) and the problem persists.
Also I create another project, including the files and... the problem is still here...
I check the project options, specifically general and debug options and I see nothing wrong.
So does anyone have an idea what may be wrong?

The output directory is `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\` and I'm compiling in Debug mode.

Comment: Avast is a well-known troublemaker.  Use garlic and silver bullets.  Don't just disable it, uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

The windows error message is misleading. It should state that, loading a library (dll) failed. You might run the program with a process monitor (see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)